# ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: servicesprice_set-TOTAL_FORMS

Tags: django, django-admin

When i am changing and saving from Inclusive To Exclusive Django admin give me following error:

```
(Hidden field TOTAL_FORMS) This field is required.
(Hidden field INITIAL_FORMS) This field is required.

ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with. Missing fields: servicesprice_set-TOTAL_FORMS, 
    servicesprice_set-INITIAL_FORMS. You may need to file a bug report if the issue persists.
```

[image]

This is happening after i override inline field. What does this mean?

```
@admin.register(Services)
class ServicesAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, EmptyFieldListFilter):
    ...
    inlines = [
        SubServiceInline,
        ServicePriceInline
    ]

    ExclusiveInlines = [
        ExclusiveServicePriceInline
    ]
    InclusiveInlines = []

    ...
    def get_inlines(self, request, obj):
        if not obj.parent_id:
            return self.inlines
        elif obj.type == 1:
            return self.InclusiveInlines
        else:
            return self.ExclusiveInlines
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm rather new here myself, but I've been struggling with the same issue today.

It turns out that `MyModelAdmin.get_inline()` is called before the `MyModel.save()` when you're saving via the admin panel like that.

This creates a conflict when you're adding an `InlineAdmin` for a related model that, in my case, wasn't created until the `MyModel.save()` function was called.

I hope that helps, and I wish I could explain it better. Just learning all of this, myself. :)

Good luck to you!